What is the meaning of storage mentioned in AWS EC2 instance pricing? How is it priced?
I see the following as the AWS EC2 price for a specific region i.e., for t4g.medium, the on-demand hourly rate is $0.0336.

Note that this is EBS only. Assume that I am out of free tier. If I do not provision any EBS storage more than the root EBS only storage of 4 GiB, is this root EBS only instance storage of 4 GiB included in the mentioned price of $0.0336? Or, do I still need to pay $0.0336 + EBS volume cost for 4 GiB?

It is best to avoid using the term "instance storage" since this refers to an old form of storage before Amazon EBS. The Amazon EC2 instance you have shown above says Memory: 4GiB which is RAM, not disk storage. There is no disk storage included in the price shown. Instead, you will be charged separately for any Amazon EBS storage you use.

EC2 Instance Part:
Lets Assume we do a math for 100Hours in a Month
t4g.medium Instance ondemand Cost = 0.0336 $/Hour
1 instances x 0.0336 USD On Demand hourly cost x 100 hours in a month = 3.360000 USD

So Instance Cost for 100Hours in a Month:
On-Demand instances (monthly): 3.360000 USD

EBS Volume Part:
Let's Assume you are using GP3 based SSD Volume of 4GB (100 Hours in a months basis)
General Purpose SSD (gp3) - IOPS : 3000 IOPS (free)
General Purpose SSD (gp3) - Throughput : 125 MBps (free)
100 total EC2 hours / 730 hours in a month = 0.14 instance months

4 GB x 0.14 instance months x 0.08 USD = 0.04 USD (EBS Storage Cost)
EBS Storage Cost: 0.04 USD

3,000 iops - 3000 GP3 iops free = 0.00 billable gp3 iops
125 MBps - 125 GP3 MBps free = 0.00 billable MBps

Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) total cost (monthly): 0.04 USD

Add both EC2 Cost and EBS Cost for a month of 100 Hours:
On-Demand instances (monthly): 3.360000 USD + Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) total cost (monthly): 0.04 USD => 3.4 USD 

Source: https://calculator.aws/#/addService?nc2=h_ql_pr_calc

Thanks. If I assume I only stop (not terminate), then I believe, it will be 3.36 USD + (4 * 0.08 USD). This part is clear so far. Now, only pending question is what does it mean to mention 4 GiB in the pricing table? How does it matter if it is 4, 5, 6 or 100 if it is anyway charged separately?

Thanks. Got the answer from the previous comment on the question. It refers to RAM not disk storage.
